# Sign in with Apple MainActor issues

Tags: ios, swift, mainactor

Swift 5.6, iOS 15.5

I have a class that is responsible for handling Sign in with Apple.

```
class SignInWithApple: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    private var view: UIView
    
    init(_ view: UIView) {
        self.view = view
    }
}
```

This class implements the delegate methods from `ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding`

This is defined by Apple as:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public protocol ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding : NSObjectProtocol {

    
    /** @abstract Return a view anchor that is most appropriate for athorization UI to be presented over.  This view will be used as a hint if a credential provider requires user interaction.
     */
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor
}
```

The implementation of this looks as follows:

```
extension SignInWithApple {
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return view.window!
    }
}
```

I added some compiler flags to have more strict `MainActor` usage checking (making sure that things that are marked as MainActor are not being called from other threads). namely:

```
-Xfrontend -warn-concurrency -Xfrontend -enable-actor-data-race-checks
```

This however gives me the following issues:

If I leave the code as-is, I get a compiler error in the `ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding` implementation:

```
Property 'window' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not be referenced from this synchronous context
```

Which makes sense as `window` should only be accessed from the main actor.

If however I change it and add `MainActor` like this:

```
    @MainActor func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return view.window!
    }
```

This gives me a warning:

```
Instance method 'presentationAnchor(for:)' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not satisfy corresponding requirement from protocol 'ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding'
```

Which makes sense, because the protocol, nor the declared function inside the protocol are marked as `MainActor` by Apple.

So my question:
How do I get rid of the error and the warning?

From what I see, I think Apple's codebase is simply not ready for strict `MainActor` enforcement.

Comment: Why is calling stuff marked with MainActor a problem if called from other threads?

Comment: Did you try Xcode 14?

Comment: Have you found any work arounds for this? I'm still seeing this issue in Xcode 15 RC

Answer (score 0):

For people out-there implementing strict concurrency.

The issue here is the fact that the `view` property is a var thus allowing a shared mutable state. The compiler is making sure you can't actually read and write the property at the same time from two different threads.

Therefore you need to make you `view` property a `let` so the compiler knows there is no risk of having two threads concurrently mutating the property.

Yet you will probably face the same issue with the `window` property which is also a `var`.

So you need to inject a `UIWindow` into you service and make it a constant.

Alternatively you can wait for Apple to make AuthenticationServices thread safe and automatically synchronized to the main thread.

Comment: But `UIView` and `UIWindow` are classes. So even if you use `let` instead of `var`, you can still modify properties on the instance.

Comment: Yes you are correct indeed yet here the issue lies with the `SignInWithApple` class and its mutable properties. However for sure if you only make the UIView a let you will still face the same problem accessing the `window` property since multiple actors can access it at the same time. 
If you inject the window directly and make it a let you should not have any issue with the class `SignInWithApple`.